# LOH fragmentation - 2015 update

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, out-of-memory, windbg

There is a lot of information available about the .NET LOH and it has been explained in various articles. However, it seems that some articles lack a bit of precision.

### Outdated information

In [Brian Rasmussen's answer (2009), program manager at Microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/a/687155/480982), he says the limit is 85000 bytes. He also let's us know that there is an even more curious case of `double[]` with a size of 1000 elements. The same 85000 limit is stated by [Maoni Stephens (MSDN, 2008), member of the CLR team](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx).

In the comments, Brian Rasmussen becomes even more exact and let's us know that it can be reproduced with a `byte[]` of 85000 bytes - 12 bytes.

### 2013 update

[Mario Hewardt (author of 'Advanced Windows Debugging')](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mariohewardt/archive/2013/06/26/no-more-memory-fragmentation-on-the-large-object-heap.aspx)  told us in 2013 that .NET 4.5.1 can now compact the LOH as well, if we tell it to do so. Since it is turned off by default, the problem remains unless you're aware of it already.

### 2015 update

I can't reproduce the `byte[]` example any more. With a short brute-force algorithm, I found out that I have to subtract 24 instead (`byte[84999-24]` in SOH, `byte[85000-24]` in LOH):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int diff = 0;
        int generation = 3;
        while (generation > 0)
        {
            diff++;
            byte[] large = new byte[85000-diff];
            generation = GC.GetGeneration(large);
        }            
        Console.WriteLine(diff);
    }
```

I also couldn't reproduce the `double[]` statement. Brute-forcing gives me 10622 elements as the border (`double[10621]` in SOH, `double[10622]` in LOH):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int size = 85000;
        int step = 85000/2;
        while (step>0)
        {
            double[] d = new double[size];
            int generation = GC.GetGeneration(d);
            size += (generation>0)?-step:step;
            step /= 2;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(size);
    }
```

This happens even if I compile the application for older .NET frameworks. It also does not depend on Release or Debug build.

How can the changes be explained?

Comment: Thanks for posting the update. The issue is really not that you can't repro `byte[85000-12]` any longer. A 32 bit process will *still* have the behavior I describe and you can verify that on the latest CLR. However, as you point out below the difference is due to the size of reference on 64 bit platforms, so to repro for 64 bit you need to take the different size of the reference into account like you show in your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The change from 12 to 24 in the `byte[]` example can be explained by the change in CPU architecture from 32 to 64 bit. In programs compiled for x64 or AnyCPU, the .NET overhead increases from 2*4 bytes (4 bytes Object Header + 4 bytes Method Table) to 2*8 bytes (8 bytes Object Header + 8 bytes Method Table). In addition, the array has a length property of 4 bytes (32 bit) versus 8 bytes (64 bits).

For the `double[]` example, just use a calculator: 85000 bytes / 64 bit for the double type = 10625 items, which is already close. Considering the .NET overhead, the result is (85000 bytes - 24 bytes) / 8 bytes per double = 10622 doubles. So there is no special handling of `double[]` any more.

BTW, I have never found any working demonstration for LOH fragmentation before, so I wrote one myself. Just compile the following code for x86 and run it. It even includes some debugging hints.

It won't work as well when compiled as x64 since Windows might increase the size of the pagefile, so the subsequent allocation of 20 MB memory could be successful again.

```
class Program
{
    static IList<byte[]> small = new List<byte[]>();
    static IList<byte[]> big = new List<byte[]>(); 

    static void Main()
    {
        int totalMB = 0;
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Allocating memory...");
            while (true)
            {
                big.Add(new byte[10*1024*1024]);
                small.Add(new byte[85000-3*IntPtr.Size]);
                totalMB += 10;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} MB allocated", totalMB);
            }
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Memory is full now. Attach and debug if you like. Press Enter when done.");
            Console.WriteLine("For WinDbg, try `!address -summary` and  `!dumpheap -stat`.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            big.Clear();
            GC.Collect();
            Console.WriteLine("Lots of memory has been freed. Check again with the same commands.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            try
            {
                big.Add(new byte[20*1024*1024]);
            }
            catch(OutOfMemoryException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It was not possible to allocate 20 MB although {0} MB are free.", totalMB);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```